# Can a SOAP web service be called a web API

Tags: rest, api

Is it possible to call a SOAP web service a web api? or is a web api a synonym for a REST Api only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is a web API, so yes. The term API gets used in a lot of different ways, but using it for a SOAP webservice is not unprecedented: SalesForce used to call their SOAP webservice their 'webservice API' but have since renamed it to 'SOAP API'.